JS Event type change / keydown / beforeinput /
I have an input element of the type number and prefilled with a zero.
Now i want to trigger some JS everytime the value changes...but

It should not be triggered if the user presses backspace fort deleting the initial zero.
It should be triggered if the user uses the arrows awailable for number fields

So this is not working because its getting triggered on backspace:
on(document, "change keydown", ".mynumberfield", function (e) {
...


Looks like you're using jQuery? Wouldn't backspace change the value too? But you Should be able to check the key property of the event to determine if it's the backspace key and then not proceed if it is. I do recommend you [edit] your question to include a [mre] so we can get the full picture.

No, its not jQuery, it is UIkit. I also thought of checking which key it is and not process it, but i thought maybe there is a better way.

The event will always fire. As mentioned, check the key and return from the event early (do nothing) if it's a key you want to ignore.
